# Using lubridate in R with unusual date formats

Tags: r, lubridate, dplyr

I have a dataset I am trying to wrangle that has the date in the format of numerical day-month abbreviation (i.e. 24-Feb). I want to use mutate and lubridate to split these into two new columns, one for day and one for month. I'm having trouble with the syntax to handle numerics and abbreviations. The following code, which I think is what I'm trying to do does not work. Thanks in advance.

```
    df <- df %>% 
mutate(Date = dm(bday))
```

Comment: There is no `dm` function in `lubridate`. If you want to convert to a date, you will have to include a year because dates by definition have a day, month and year.

Comment: Yeah, thats the issue, the dates don't have a year attached to them, it's just day-month abbrevation.

Comment: lubridate can cope with 'dm' orders, but it's going to assume they;re all this year. i.e. `parse_date_time("24-Feb", "dm")`

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to `paste` the correct year into your column, e.g. using `stringr::str_c`.

```
data.frame(Date = "24-Feb") %>% 
    mutate(Date = dmy(stringr::str_c(Date, "2021")))
#        Date
# 1 2021-02-24
```

You can check what objects are provided by a package using `objects`.

```
objects("package:lubridate", pattern = "dm")
# [1] "dmicroseconds" "dmilliseconds" "dminutes"      "dmy"          
# [5] "dmy_h"         "dmy_hm"        "dmy_hms"       "ydm"          
# [9] "ydm_h"         "ydm_hm"        "ydm_hms"
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1. `dmy()` with `truncated = 1L`

The `ymd()` family of `lubridate` functions accepts a `truncated` parameter which tells how many formats may be omitted. Thus,

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- tibble(bday = c("24-Feb", "25-Apr"))

df %>% 
  mutate(Date = dmy(bday, truncated = 1L))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 2
>   bday   Date      
>   <chr>  <date>    
> 1 24-Feb 2021-02-24
> 2 25-Apr 2021-04-25
> ```

### 2. `separate()`

The OP has requested

> I want to use mutate and lubridate to split these into two new
> columns, one for day and one for month.

Splitting `bday` in a `Day` and a `Month` column can be achieved directly without the intermediate step to create a `Date` column:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  separate(bday, c("Day", "Month"), "-", remove = FALSE)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
>   bday   Day   Month
>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>
> 1 24-Feb 24    Feb  
> 2 25-Apr 25    Apr
> ```